# Predictor variables in Multinomial Logistic Regression

Tags: regression, logistic, multinomial-distribution

Is it always better to have categorical predictor variables when performing a multinomial logistic regression analysis? or can it be done using continuous predictor variables? If a predictor variable should always be categorical, what is the reason behind it?

Answer (score 1):

Multinomial logistic, like other forms of regression, can deal with any sort of predictor.